# Searching for objects in a Dictionary whose key is a "Hashed String"

Tags: c#, string, hash, dictionary

I have a dictionary whose key is currently a string

```
m_AllGameSounds = new Dictionary<string, soundFile>();
```

I was looking to change these strings to hashed strings because there are things that happen in my game that may amount to per frame checks on this dictionary and I really dont want that to mean string compare lookups through a dictionary, so, I looked up the string hashing facilities in C# and stumbled upon this page :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx

The problem is that the page suggests that I should not do exactly what I am trying to do, because collisions are possible. I am not certain how big of a deal this is for a small data set like mine (probably 50 - 60 entries) however, I was wondering if there is some other efficient way to do the same.

Comment: "i really dont want that to mean string compare lookups through a dictionary" - why not? Do you understand what a dictionary lookup actually consists of? (In particular, it already uses hashing, and is already efficient...) Do you have any evidence that this is causing a performance bottleneck?

Comment: I can assure you, if it's only 50 or 60 strings, you have no reason to look elsewhere. The C# Dictionary uses hashing under the hood, and would still perform very well with many thousands of strings. In fact, if this turned out to be the bottleneck in your code, I would be astonished.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am from a C++ background so I assume things are not efficient unless I have done something to make them so, I am particularly concerned for the dictionary because it is a templated collection, for all the compiler knows I could have put in a type as the key which was not a string at all (ofcourse I would have to specify how to compare them), but unless there is a specialized implementation for comparing string keyed dictionaries, I assume that it is not optimizing it using hashes.

Comment: @JonSkeet would you happen to know of a web resource where I can read up on how this specialized compare is happening ?

edit : nvm , checked the remarks on the Dictionary documentation

Comment: @angryInsomniac: Then you're making assumptions which could easily have been shown to be false by reading the documentation. Read the remarks of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx - it specifically talks about hashing. The "specialized implementation" is on a per-type basis due to using `GetHashCode`. Even if you *couldn't* validate that it was using hashing just by reading the optimization, you've skipped straight from "I might have a performance problem" to "I'm going to try to solve that problem" without validating whether it's *actually* a problem.

Comment: Dictionaries use `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` instances to calculate the hash and perform key comparison. The default implementation (created through `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` will eventually fall back on the key's `GetHashCode()` and `Equals` methods.

Comment: @JonSkeet Interestingly I commented 2 mins before you stating that I have reached similar conclusions from similar sources, thanks for the info though.

Comment: @angryInsomniac: I *started* writing the comment a bit before you posted your comment, but it took me a while to check the docs on my flaky 3G connection.

Comment: If the strings are known in advance you can create a [minimal perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). In this case it would be overkill but certainly an interesting approach to hashing. See [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) and [CMPH](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/) for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @Jon Skeet in the first comment, it seems that the Dictionary container is already optimized for lookups, according to the documentation listed here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Ref# the "Remarks" section, the lookup cost is nearly O(1), because the Dictionary class is implemented as a hash table.

If anyone is interested in knowing more about this, I suggest reading the documentation at the indicated link.

Thanks,
Nik